# SQL Loop through list of integers and insert line into table for each

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table in which I need to insert over 100 rows, each with only one unique value between them. Currently, I am using an INSERT statement to put in one row at a time which is becoming increasingly frustrating. It looks like this

```
INSERT INTO tblTableName
    (columnName1, columnName2, columnName3, columnName4)
VALUES
    (sameData1, sameData2, sameData3, variableIntegerData)
```

For each new entry I make into the table, i replace variableIntegerData and execute the code.

Is there a way i can have my data in a one dimension array (which could look like this)

```
(907, 908, 875, 876, 878, 885 ...)
```

And then run the code so it inserts a line for each element in that array? I have considered making a temporary table to store the data however that would just be double handling anyway.

Any help on this would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you executing this? Through SSMS directly, or from a client app such as C# or PHP

Answer (score 1):

Create a derived table with the `VALUES` constructor (a table with values you create on the fly) and use a regular `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` to reference your created rows and add additional constants for the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO tblTableName (
    columnName1, 
    columnName2, 
    columnName3, 
    columnName4)
SELECT
    sameData1,
    sameData2,
    sameData3,
    V.IntegerData
FROM
    (VALUES (907), (908), (875), (876), (878), (885)) AS V(IntegerData)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the format of the data that you have is now, but assuming that it is a CSV, this should do nicely

```
INSERT INTO tblTableName
   (tblTableName, sameValue1, sameValue2, sameValue3)
SELECT i.value, 'foo' , 'bar' , 'baz'
FROM STRING_SPLIT('907,908,875,876,878,885', ',') AS i;
```

Comment: Champion, this worked exactly as I wanted it to. Thank you so much!